# An alternate approach for session handling in PHP

Tags: php, session

I am working on a Chat application that works inside an `<iframe>` embedded into websites. It's built using CodeIgniter.

Because of recent cookie policies by certain mainstream browsers and permanent block on 3rd-party cookies for pages loaded within `<iframe>`es, my chat application isn't working because it uses PHP Session and that requires cookies to be enabled to work.

I have Googled a lot, and tried almost every solution, nothing works. The only solution left for me now is to get rid of Session handling and try to do the same using something similar.

I have tried to use the Caching library instead, but Caching doesn't work like sessions, so it might not be an ideal solution.

Is there any library or approach which I can use to replace the session system easily?

Comment: What browsers are to be affected? I can't reproduce it on Windows with latest stable versions of Firefox or Chrome so I presume it's something to be rolled out in the incoming months :-?

Comment: It's Safari and Chrome on any iOS device (Mac and iPhone tested).

Comment: You can always include the session id in the url? Access it as a $_GET parameter. I would be tempted to encrypt it to prevent tampering with it.